# Finding Longest Weak Twin that occurs as a subsequence of a given sequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subsequence

Suppose `a[]` and `b[]` are finite sequences of integers in which there are no pairs `a[i] = a[j]` or `b[i] = b[j]` for (i != j). Then, `a[]` and `b[]` are called weak twins if for all `i`, `a[i] < a[i+1]` iff `b[i] < b[i+1]` (which implies, `a[i] > a[i+1]` iff `b[i] > b[i+1]`).

Suppose `s[]` is again some finite sequence of integers with pairwise distinct values. The twin-width of `s[]` is the length of the maximum pair of disjoint subsequences `a[], b[]` of `s[]` such that `a[]` and `b[]` are weak twins.

For example, the twin-width of the sequence `[1, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2]` is 3 because we can extract the two following subsequences from this sequences which are weak-twins: `[1, 3, 2]` and `[4, 6, 5]`.

It is clear that the twin-width of a sequence of length 2n is at most n, but in many cases, it can be much smaller.

Given a sequence `s[]`, how can we find its twin-width?

---

I have tried a simple dynamic programming approach where `dp[i, j]` represents the length of the longest pair of weak twin subsequences which end in `s[i]` and `s[j]` respectively. To compute dp[i, j], I want to see whether all sequences ending at i', j' for i' < i and j' < j can be extended or not. Unfortunately, it appears that this approach does not seem to work since we do not know that the sequence we are extending already contains `s[i]` or `s[j]`.

I am thinking of this as a slight generalization of the longest increasing sequence problem. So, maybe there is a better algorithm?